# Magento2 Module does not use catalog_category_view.xml

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am trying to update the `catalog_category_view.xml` with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<page xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/advancedCatalog.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Js" name="advanced_catalog_js" template="Vendor_Module::js.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

The file is in `/app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/`.

However it does not get injected. I cleared my caches and such, however, no change to Frontend. What am I doing wrong?

This is my structure of the module:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Seems some codes of that layout is wrong**

```
<css src="Vendor_Module/css/advancedCatalog.css"/>
```

*This above code is wrong,it should be*

```
<css src="Vendor_Module::css/advancedCatalog.css"/>
```

Comment: Sure, its a typo. However this has not given any solution to the problem. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento with Page Builder (c. 2.4+) you need to put your catalog_category_view.xml in the app/design folder:

app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_PageBuilder/page_layout/catalog_category_view.xml